# body parameters not being sent with retrofit POST request

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I am trying to send one object to api (using Retrofit) with POST request from my android app but the parameters are not being sent. The retrofit interface function is as follows:

```kotlin
@POST(URLs.REGISTER)
suspend fun registerUser(@Body user: User) : Response<Result>
```

I am calling this function from the viewmodel as follows:

```kotlin
suspend fun registerUser(user: User) : Response<Result> {
    return RetrofitInstance.api.registerUser(user)
}
```

The `User` object is as follows:

```kotlin
data class  User(
    val email: String,
    val name: String,
    val password : String,
    val auth_token: String = ""
)
```

While sending the API request, I am setting all parameter values as provided by user except `auth_token` which is not needed in this case.
Also, I am using `PHP` api as follows:

```php
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
// Converts it into a PHP object
$data = json_decode($json);

$response = array();
$result = new Result();

if ($data != null) {
    if (!empty($data->user->name) && !empty($data->user->email) && !empty($data->user->password)) {
    } else {
        $result->setErrorStatus(true);
        $result->setMessage("insufficient parameters");
    }
} else {
    $result->setErrorStatus(true);
    $result->setMessage("no data received");
}

$response['error'] = $result->isError();
$response['message'] = $result->getMessage();
echo json_encode($response);
```

As per the above code, I get the response message as "insufficient parameters" which is the case where it has received the `User` object but not received any of the data. the same which I tried from Postman works fine. What it might be causing so?

I also tried setting header as `@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")` but that also did not work.

Comment: What is the value of `$json` when sending the request from Android?

Comment: @zomega its `{"auth_token":"","email":"abc@gmail.com","name":"Abc","password":"1"}`

Comment: Change `$data->user->name` to `$data->name` and so on. If this is not what you want you can create a data class named `RegisterUserRequest` with just one single member of type `User`.

Comment: @zomega Yes, it worked. Thanks